# Android bouncing ball

Tags: java, android, accelerometer

So i'm just trying to make a ball bounce around the screen which should slow down due to gravity and reflect (bounce) from the wall like a normal ball would.
Can someone give some basics and VERY simple implementation of this?
Other examples seem a bit "overdone" and seem to go beyond what I want to do.
I've tried this:

```
public void updateLogic() {

    if (x < -1) {

        xPos += (-x * gravity);
    } else if (x > 1) {

        xPos -= (x * gravity);
    }
    if (y > 1) {

        yPos += (y * gravity);
    } else if (y < -1) {

        yPos -= (-y * gravity);
    }
}
```

This is the closest I got by myself.
By the way the x and y values are from the accelerometer.
Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What does your code example not do that you want fixed?

Comment: You'll also need to keep track of and update xVelocity and yVelocity.

Comment: Problem is I haven't added velocity yet and i'm pretty sure thats what im missing to make it perform that way i want. Second problem is I don't quite understand how to implement that so I was wondering if I could get a clear simple explanation of how to do so and how it works. Im no math person so yea...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you'll need 3 things for this, forces (x and y, which you have), velocities (call them xVel and yVel) and positions (xPos and yPos which you also have). The position of the ball is updated (in the simplest way) by:

```
xPos += dt*xVel; 
yPos += dt*yVel;

xVel += dt*x;
yVel += dt*y;
```

The variable 'dt' is the *timestep*, which controls how fast the ball will move. If this is set too large, though, the program will be unstable! Try dt = 0.001 or so to start and gradually set it higher.

Then, to get the ball to reflect from the walls, just flip the velocity if it hits a wall:

```
if (xPos > xMax) {
    xPos = xMax;
    xVel *= -1.0;
} else if (xPos < 0.0) {
    xPos = 0.0;
    xVel *= -1.0;
}
```

and the same for y. The 'xPos = ...' is just to stop the ball going off the edge of the screen. If you'd like the ball to bounce a little less every time it hits a wall, change the '-1.0' to '-0.9' or something (this is the [coefficient of restitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_restitution)).

Hopefully that should be all. Good luck!

Comment: Wow thanks that helped a lot. I am using the x and y values from the accelerometer as "force" and using 2.0f as the xVel and yVel. Also set dt as 0.1f and seems like there is no gravity taking place. I need to still experiment with different values but so far this has helped me greatly.

Answer (score 2):

[Youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3vR-AQJ1de0)

[Source code available at github](https://github.com/I82Much/BouncingBall).

1. Your x coordinate should not be affected by gravity.
2. I would advise against using accelerometers until you understand how the physics work for the simple case.

Break it up into stages.  First, ensure that you can get the ball falling at a constant velocity.

Once you have that working, worry about the gravity causing the velocity to increase.

Once you have that working, worry about the intersection with walls and velocity changes.  A simple algorithm for bouncing off the walls would be to multiply the x velocity by -1 when you hit a vertical wall, and multiply the y velocity by -1 when you hit a horizontal wall.

Comment: I've made a ball falling at constant speed. Then implemented collision detection with the walls (boundaries). Only problem now is implementing the gravity. According to what you said, I should have a constant (gravity) affecting the velocity on the y axis resulting in yVel increasing?

Comment: Exactly.  (Assuming your y positive axis points down, which it should in both Android and Swing).  See the source code link I posted.

Comment: BTW when you saw that I was affecting gravity on the X axis, it was because I was trying to implement gravity in all directions on both axis according to how the phone was being hold. Simply put, user controls gravity direction, ultimately affecting the ball.

Answer (score 2):

Some comments on your actual code:

- Both of these lines do exactly the same thing:

  ```
  yPos -= (-y * gravity);
  yPos += (y * gravity);
  ```

  likewise, both of these lines do the same thing:

  ```
  xPos += (-x * gravity);
  xPos -= (x * gravity);
  ```
- You are not handling the cases `-1 <= x <= 1` or `-1 <= y <= 1`

Some comments on the concepts:

- Start with one ball.
- You want the ball to have two separate velocities (both either positive or negative), one in the x-direction and one in the y-direction.  Every frame, add those velocities to the ball's position.
- Then add collision detection.  Check each frame if the center of the ball is outside the screen.  If it is, make it bounce *(the easiest way to do this is to make the ball's y-velocity positive when it goes off the most-negative y-value displayed on the screen; and do similarly for the other screen-edges)*.
- Improve the collision detection:  see if you can figure out how to check if *any* part of the ball it outside the screen *(hint: to check if the ball is off the left-side of the screen, you only need to check the left-most coordinate of the ball)*
- Then take gravity into consideration - gravity will be a constant number subtracted from the y-velocity every frame, until the y-velocity hits 0.