# Can we have auto bouncing balls in android

Tags: android

Can we have auto bouncing balls(say 3 to 5 balls bouncing automatically with medium pace here and there on the screen) in android. If yes, then what will be needed to start with it.
Target device : 2.2
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at this : http://stuffthathappens.com/blog/2009/03/21/android-bouncing-ball-demo/
and see the same discussion here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513902/android-bouncing-ball [Bouncing Ball](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/android/Android_2D.html) [At Dinesh blogspot](http://dinesh707.blogspot.com/2011/03/android-create-bouncing-ball-on-screen.html)

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.anddev.org/a_bouncing_ball_-_basic_graphics_animation_demo-t283.html) you can find a good tutorial that shows you how to do that for 1 ball. It shouldn't be too difficult to extend this to 3 to 5 balls.