# How to change the trajectory of a button when it hits a wall in android?

Tags: android

I defined a circular button in my app and want to set it in continuous motion so that whenever it touches the boundary (i.e walls), it gets reflected. 
I am currently using the following code to move it to a specific point.

```
button.animate().translationX(x).setDuration(5000).start();
button.animate().translationY(y).setDuration(5000).start();
```

However, I want to set it in continuous motion so that it gets reflected whenever it touches the boundaries. Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513902/android-bouncing-ball

Comment: The question you mentioned involves gravity and accelerometer while my question doesn't involve any of those.